# How can I extract URLs from HTML content with a Ruby regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex

This is an example since it is not easy to explain:

```
<li id="l_f6a1ok3n4d4p" class="online"> <div class="link"> <a href="javascript:show('f6a1ok3n4d4p','random%20strings%204',%20'site2.com');%20" onclick="visited('f6a1ok3n4d4p');" style="float:left;">random strings - 4</a> <a style="float:left; display:block; padding-top:3px;" href="http://www.webtrackerplus.com/?page=flowplayerregister&amp;a_aid=&amp;a_bid=&amp;chan=flow"><img border="0" src="/resources/img/fdf.gif"></a> <!-- a class="none" href="#">random strings - 4  site2.com - # - </a --> </div> <div class="params"> <span>Submited: </span>7 June 2015  | <span>Host: </span>site2.com </div> <div class="report"> <a title="" href="javascript:report(3191274,%203,%202164691,%201)" class="alert"></a> <a title="" href="javascript:report(3191274,%203,%202164691,%200)" class="work"></a> <b>100% said work</b> </div> <div class="clear"></div> </li> <li id="l_zsgn82c4b96d" class="online"> <div class="link"> <a href="javascript:show('zsgn82c4b96d','random%20strings%204',%20'site1.com');%20" onclick="visited('zsgn82c4b96d');" style
```

In the above content I want to extract from

```
javascript:show('f6a1ok3n4d4p','random%20strings%204',%20'site2.com')
```

the string `"f6a1ok3n4d4p"` and `"site2.com"` then make it as

```
http://site2.com/f6a1ok3n4d4p
```

and same for

```
javascript:show('zsgn82c4b96d','random%20strings%204',%20'site1.com')
```

to become

```
http://site1.com/zsgn82c4b96d
```

I need it to be done with Ruby regex.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried toward solving this problem? There are several things you're asking for, but you haven't showed any code you've written, so it really sounds like you're asking us to write a solution for you, which isn't how Stack Overflow works. Also, *why* do you need it to be done using a regular expression? Which part? Also, please reduce your sample HTML to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate what you're working on. Anything beyond that wastes our time as we try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed like this:

```
require 'uri'
str = "javascript:show('f6a1ok3n4d4p','random%20strings%204',%20'site2.com')"

# regex scan to get values within javascript:show
vals = str.scan(/javascript:show\((.*)\)/)[0][0].split(',')
# => ["'f6a1ok3n4d4p'", "'random%20strings%204'", "%20'site2.com'"]

# joining resultant Array elements to generate url
url = "http://" +  URI.decode(a.last).tr("'", '').strip + "/" + a.first.tr("'", '')
# => "http://site2.com/f6a1ok3n4d4p"
```

obviously my answer is not foolproof. You can make it better with checks for what if `scan` returns `[]`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, though the regexp isn't particularly flexible.

```
js_link_regex = /href=\"javascript:show\('([^']+)','[^']+',%20'([^']+)'\)/
link = <<eos
  <li id="l_f6a1ok3n4d4p" class="online"> <div class="link"> <a href="javascript:show('f6a1ok3n4d4p','random%20strings%204',%20'site2.com');%20" onclick="visited('f6a1ok3n4d4p');" style="float:left;">random strings - 4</a> <a style="float:left; display:block; padding-top:3px;" href="http://www.webtrackerplus.com/?page=flowplayerregister&amp;a_aid=&amp;a_bid=&amp;chan=flow"><img border="0" src="/resources/img/fdf.gif"></a> <!-- a class="none" href="#">random strings - 4  site2.com - # - </a --> </div> <div class="params"> <span>Submited: </span>7 June 2015  | <span>Host: </span>site2.com </div> <div class="report"> <a title="" href="javascript:report(3191274,%203,%202164691,%201)" class="alert"></a> <a title="" href="javascript:report(3191274,%203,%202164691,%200)" class="work"></a> <b>100% said work</b> </div> <div class="clear"></div> </li> <li id="l_zsgn82c4b96d" class="online"> <div class="link"> <a href="javascript:show('zsgn82c4b96d','random%20strings%204',%20'site1.com');%20" onclick="visited('zsgn82c4b96d');" style
eos

matches = link.scan(js_link_regex)
matches.each do |match|
  puts "http://#{match[1]}/#{match[0]}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To just match your case,

```
str = "javascript:show('f6a1ok3n4d4p','random%20strings%204',%20'site2.com')"

parts = str.scan(/'([\w|\.]+)'/).flatten # => ["f6a1ok3n4d4p", "site2.com"]

puts "http://#{parts[1]}/#{parts[0]}" # => http://site2.com/f6a1ok3n4d4p
```